# Using wget and text array usage

Tags: bash, shell, wget

Quick question. Currently using this to get header expiry info.

```
wget -O /dev/null -S $1 2>&1 | grep -q -m 1 "Expires: Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT" && echo "Yes"  || echo "No"
```

With execution via "`./is-drupal www.URL.com`"

How could I iterate through an array in a text document that would be like

```
    www.URL1.com
    www.URL2.com
    www.URL3.com
    etc.
```

Then if the value returned "Yes" it would save the Yes URLs to a new text file.

Your best input is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r line; do
  wget -O /dev/null -S "$line" 2>&1 | grep -q -m 1 "Expires: Sun, 19 Nov 1978 05:00:00 GMT"
  if [ ${PIPESTATUS[1]} -eq 0 ]; then     # check greps return code
    echo "Yes"
    echo "$line" >> yes_urls.txt
  else
    echo "No"
  fi
done < text.txt
```